# Generate the unique pattern for the given 4 cases using pattern regx in java

Tags: java

Here is my input data(as a text file):

```
Stream: (4040) "StreamTestDeleteit"
Stream: (4037) "RBL_RB_REF_VMPSufgf_Int" <-> (4009) "RBL_DAI_BR222313_VMPS_Android"
Stream: (4002) "HPNEtd_Team23_dep_20190616"
Stream: (4002) "HPNE-td_Team23_dep_20190616fg"
```

Output i am excepting is :

```
StreamTestDeleteit
RBL_RB_REF_VMPSufgf_Int
HPNEtd_Team23_dep_20190616
HPNE-td_Team23_dep_20190616fg
```

Output i am getting :

```
StreamTestDeleteit
RBL_DAI_BR222313_VMPS_Android
HPNEtd_Team23_dep_20190616
HPNE-td_Team23_dep_20190616fg
```

so what i want is need one pattern which will work for all the 4 cases

My Snippet:

```
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(filepath);
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String strLine;
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Stream:(.*) \"(.*)\"");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(strLine);
            while (m.find())
            {
                    streamInp = m.group(2);
                    streamMatcher.add(streamInp);
            }
        }
        br.close();
```

Comment: What have you tried? Or are you just hoping we'll write your code for you?

Comment: @Andreas  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Stream:(.*) \"(.*)\""); maybe you can compile this pattern on regex101 online compiler

Comment: Are you applying the regex one line at a time? Your question should include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you've tried, and show/explain how the output differs from what you expected.

Comment: Anyway, try `"Stream:.*? \"(.*?)\""`

Comment: @Andreas its edited with snippet and yes the given pattern does not work

Comment: For better performance, this might work too: `"\"([^\"]*)\""`, if you change `while (m.find())` to `if (m.find())`

Comment: @Andreas nope its not working

Comment: @Andreas please look at case 2,

Comment: Yes it is, see answer for proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the regex as previously given in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59632903/generate-the-unique-pattern-for-the-given-4-cases-using-pattern-regx-in-java?noredirect=1#comment105429129_59632903), and it worked fine with the code given in the question. See below.

I do however also have a few comments on the code:

- Don't include a `DataInputStream` in the stream pipeline.
- Use the newer Java 7+ NIO.2 methods for reading files.
- Use the Java 7+ try-with-resources statement to manage the closing of the file stream.

Updated code with working regex:

```
try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(filepath))) {
    for (String strLine; (strLine = br.readLine()) != null; ) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Stream:.*? \"(.*?)\"");
        for (Matcher m = p.matcher(strLine); m.find(); ) {
            String streamInp = m.group(1);
            System.out.println(streamInp);
        }
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
StreamTestDeleteit
RBL_RB_REF_VMPSufgf_Int
HPNEtd_Team23_dep_20190616
HPNE-td_Team23_dep_20190616fg
```